# groovy script to remove users from jenkins project role alone?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

```html
import hudson.security.*
    import jenkins.security.*
    import jenkins.model.Jenkins

    def sids = Jenkins.instance.authorizationStrategy.getAllSIDs()
    return sids

In the Build Section;

    def removeAMP(Job jobName, user ) {
       println jobName.name.center(80,'-')
  
       def authorizationMatrixProperty = jobName.getProperty(AuthorizationMatrixProperty.class)
       Map<Permission,Set<String>> Permissions = authorizationMatrixProperty.getGrantedPermissions()
       println "Permission Map Before: " + Permissions + cr
       println "Permission Values: " + Permissions.values() + cr
  
       for (Set<String> permissionUsers:Permissions.values()) {
         permissionUsers.remove(user)  
       }
       println "Permission Map After: " + Permissions + cr
       jobName.save();
    }
```

I created a job in jenkins with "Execute system grrovy script" for removing users from project role not from jenkins global role.with following scripts,but am getting error as follows:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class Job 
 @ line 10, column 19.
       def removeAMP(Job jobName, user ) {
                     ^

1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:861)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:550)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:499)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:302)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:281)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:723)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:680)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:666)
at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:81)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
```

Build step 'Execute system Groovy script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Please help me with correct script.Thanks in advance
Ashif

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to add

```
import hudson.model.Job
```

Comment: I need to add "import hudson.model.Job" or no need?I added and checked got below error:                                                             ERROR: Build step failed with exception
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.getAllSIDs() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getSIDs(java.lang.String), getClass()

Comment: Looks like the import solved the first compilation error.  This second error is more complicated. You're using a custom auth strategy plugin. You need to look at this code and any documentation.  You'll need a colleague at your company to help you progress any further with this.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks a lot Chim, if u could solve this  ,please help me on this.or else do u have any groovy script for this task?